# updating content with php nav bar and else is statements

Tags: php, html, css

Home page loads with one error,

> Notice: Undefined index: CONTACT in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/lpnew/index.php on line 5

None of the links stay active nor do they switch the content.

Index page:

```
<?php $pg = 'index'; ?>
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
<?php 
    $pg = $_GET[$pg];
    if ($pg == "services") {
        include("services.php");
    } elseif($pg == "employees") {
        include("employees.php");
    } elseif($pg == "contact") {
        include("contact.php");
    } else {
        include("home.php");
    };
?>
<?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Navigation bar which is in `header.php`:

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    "index" => "HOME", 
    "services" => "SERVICES", 
    "employees" => "EMPLOYEES", 
    "contact" => "CONTACT"
); 
$pg = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? $_GET['pg'] : "";
foreach ($pages as $url => $pg) {
    echo '<li ';
    if ($pg == $url) {
        echo '<li><a class=active href="index.php?p='
        . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($url)). '">' 
        . htmlspecialchars($pg) . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' . $pg . '</a></li>';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
$pg = (isset($_GET['pg'])) ? $_GET['pg'] : "";
foreach ($pages as $url => $pg) {
```

You are redefining $pg so that it resolves to the last index of $pages. 
This line is trying to read `$_GET['CONTACT']` which is undefined:

```
$pg = $_GET[$pg];
if ($pg == "services") {
    include("services.php");
} elseif($pg == "employees") {
    include("employees.php");
} elseif($pg == "contact") {
    include("contact.php");
} else {
    include("home.php");
};
```

As sverri pointed out already, all you have to do is change the value part of your loop:

```
foreach ($pages as $url => $val) {
    echo '<li ';
    if ($val == $url) {
        echo '<li><a class=active href="index.php?p='
        . htmlspecialchars(urlencode($url)). '">' 
        . htmlspecialchars($val) . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="index.php?p=' . $url . '">' . $val . '</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because of this line:

```
<?php include('includes/header.php'); ?>
```

In it you loop over the `$pages` array using `$pg` as the variable that holds the value:

```
foreach ($pages as $url => $pg) {
    // ...
}
```

This overrides the original value of `$pg`, as defined in your index file, with the last value of the array (in this case `'CONTACT'`).

To fix this you can just change the name of the variable in the loop, like this:

```
foreach ($pages as $url => $someOtherName) {
    // ...
}
```